# I'm duplicating my strpos keyword check but I don't want to

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

I am pulling multiple values ($arr) from list of keywords ($keywords). Later I'm using strpos to check if that keyword existis in a document.

I could just duplicate the whole code and add every $arr manually one by one, like: strpos($element,$arr[0]); strpos($element,$arr[1]); strpos($element,$arr[2]);.

Can anyone help me set it up so that I don't have to do it the long way. Lets say I need a total of 20 $arr checks. That would be $arr[0] to $arr[19].

```
<?php

$str= "$keywords";
$arr=explode(",",$str);

// print_r($arr);

$data = file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/posts.txt');

$data=str_replace(array('<', '>', '\\', '/', '='), "", $data);

foreach($data as $element) 

{

$element = trim($element);

$check_keyword = strpos($element,$arr[0]);
if ($check_keyword !== false) {
$pieces = explode("|", $element);   

echo "

" . $pieces[0] . "  

<a href=/blog/" . $pieces[2] . "/" . $pieces[3] . "/ ><b><font color=#21b5ec>" . $pieces[4] . "</font></b></a>  <br>

";    

}

else {
echo "";
}

}

?>
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand it,the code is incomplete. Why are you not using a function?

Comment: you mean strpos_array function? I tryed that but I think I made something wrong.

Comment: I posted an answer, take a look.

Comment: Do you want to check if any value in $arr is in $element, or if all of them are in it?

Comment: Maybe `in_array` could be of help here?

Comment: @Nick I want to check all of them. And If at least one $arr is present I want it to trigger.

Comment: See my answer. It can check for any or all of the values in $arr being in $element.

Comment: Did my answer not solve your problem? If not, could you provide more info so I can hopefully improve the answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Sorry for not asnwering sooner - I went to the countryside and was offline for some time.

Comment: @Nick O and btw it worked just fine :D

Comment: Cool. It's always great to get out of town.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check every value in `$arr` against `$element` then the easiest way to do it is with [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php).

If you want to test whether **every** value in `$arr` is in `$element`, you can use this:

```
$check_keyword = array_reduce($arr, function ($carry, $item) use($element) {
        return $carry && (strpos($element, $item) !== false);
    }, true);
```

If you only want to check if **any** value in `$arr` is in `$element`, you can use this:

```
$check_keyword = array_reduce($arr, function ($carry, $item) use($element) {
        return $carry || (strpos($element, $item) !== false);
    }, false);
```

Comment: It's working. Thanks you very much. I needed the second (any value) version of the code.